# AlphaSSL intermediate CA certificate revoked

Tags: safari, security, keychain, macos, certificate

I'm unable to access JQuery CDN as Safari states that the certificate `AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2` is revoked.

Recently, I also had this problem with Wikipedia. However, accessing the page in Firefox works, it only shows the error in Safari and Chrome.

Why did this happen even though the certificate states that expires in 2024?

What would happen if I click 'Continue'?

[image: Image 1]

Browser: Safari Version 10.0
OS: macOS Sierra 10.12

Comment: Related but **no** duplicate: [How to tell why macOS thinks that a certificate is revoked?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257080/how-to-tell-why-macos-thinks-that-a-certificate-is-revoked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificates can be unexpired but still revoked, as shown in your screenshot.

Specifically the issue here seems to be a [problem with GlobalSign](https://downloads.globalsign.com/acton/fs/blocks/showLandingPage/a/2674/p/p-008f/t/page/fm/0); a configuration problem caused some browsers to believe that intermediate certificates (such as those issued by AlphaSSL) were revoked when in fact they were not.

As of five days ago, the issue was to work itself out in about four days, as cached responses for intermediate verification expired. Obviously it's not quite there yet. In your case, you can safely check the box to Always trust "AlphaSSL CA - 256SHA - G2", and click Continue.

Comment: Please, do **not** check this box. This will make your system trust the certificate even in the case it is legitimately revoked. There are ways to clear the cache in another question which is referenced in the comments.